# How to add remove border from text field

Tags: jquery

I have a text box in html form like this

```
'&lt input id="yourinput" type="text" &gt'
```

Once user enters text in it and moves out i want to make the border to 1 px (so that it does not look like a normal text field). I achieve this by

```
$("#searchforstatus").css("border", "1px");
```

Now, when the user comes back to the text field, i want to make the text field look like original normal looking text field with the exiting value in it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/576319/reset-an-input-controls-border-color-html-javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you want the `input` to look different only when it contains a value, I'd suggest this:

```
$(document).ready(
    function(){
        $('#textInput').blur(
            function(){
                if ($(this).val()) {
                    $(this).addClass('bordered');   
                }
            });
        $('#textInput').focus(
            function(){
                $(this).removeClass('bordered');  
            });
    });
```

And define the `bordered` css class in the css file (rather than adding/removing css properties in jQuery with [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/)), for example:

```
.bordered {
    border: 1px solid #f00;
}
```

[Demo at JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/m5hDm/1/).

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
$("#searchforstatus").css("border", "");
```

It looks like `$("#searchforstatus").css("border", null)` worked prior to 1.4.3, but it wasn't ever actually valid: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/7233

Answer (score 1):

I think the best and simple solution is:

```
$("#searchforstatus").css("border", "none");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Add border when user enters text field
$("#yourinput").focus(function() {
    $(this).css("border", "1px");
});

// Remove border when user leaves text field
$("#yourinput").blur(function() {
    $(this).css("border", "0");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

do it strictly in the CSS, don't use javascript for it, that's like using a hammer for a staple..

```
<style>
#searchforstatus{
border:none;
}


#searchforstatus:focus{
border:1px solid silver;
}

</style>
```

OR. create classes with border:none and border;1px and assign/unassign them at will.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#yourinput").focus(function() {
     $(this).css("border", "");
}

$("yourinput").blur(function() {
   if($(this).val() != "")
          $(this).css("border", "1px");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use jquery mobile and if you test it for mobile you need to add the following code in your css file

```
textarea:focus, input:focus{
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);    
    -webkit-user-modify: read-write-plaintext-only;
}
```

It is working for me